# Join same table to display rows as colomn in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a scenario where I need to take few rows from column and make it as separate column.

My present table:

```
Id  Description
1   abc
2   abc
3   abc
4   abc
1   xyz
2   xyz
3   xyz
4   xyz
```

Required output:

```
id  Desp1   Desp2
1   abc     xyz
2   abc     xyz
3   abc     xyz
4   abc     xyz
```

Can any one help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the `listagg` function and a combination of `instr` and `substr` functions, instead of a self Join.

```
select id,substr(Description, 0, instr(Description, ',',1,1)-1) Desp1,
substr(Description, instr(Description, ',',1,1)+1) Desp2
from
(select id, listagg(Description,',') within group (order by Description) as 
Description from sam group by id)
```

**Note**: The above query delimits the `Description` field by comma, and splits only into two columns as depicted in your example.

Comment: its not working for me..giving error,..my query is like                          select id, description from(select *...);

Comment: What error are you getting? and what query have you tried?